# Best way to send data from a show.route to a different RessourceController

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel with a lof of RessourceControllers. No I'm thinkin about a best practise to implement a form in a show.route of RessourceController A. This Form should be send to the store function in a different ResourceController B. This works fine.

But, for example, after processing the store in Controller B, i'd like to redirect back to show.route of Controller A. Of course, I'm missing the data.

And: I'd like to do some validation on the store function in Controller B - But again, the validation will not return the user to show.route of Controller A.

So I'm wondering if I don't understand the architecture concept. Do you have any advisory for me?

Comment: Could you provide some codes on your project?

Comment: the best practice is controllers are not meant to interact with each other. refactor your code in controller into other class and use them.